# Spacing results in Solr bbox by geodistance

Tags: solr

Is there a way to create a bounding box query with results that don't return in tight groupings?

e.g. If I'm writing a search with something like &fq=[24.0,-29 TO 24.5,-29.5] and there are 1000 results in that area, is there a way to have a bit more evenly distributed group of pins if &count=20. This is a maps interface and I don't want overlapping results, I could cluster, but I'm really interested in still retrieving a small number of documents that are distributed across that area more evenly.

Comment: Clustering on the client is usually the best way to solve this for users (to tell them that there actually are multiple hits there). You could also [hack it by using heatmap faceting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html#SpatialSearch-HeatmapFaceting)

Answer (score 0):

Will this solve your case if you are able to return several groups of results based on distance from your query point? Like returning 20 results with distance between 0 and 1 km, 20 more results with distance between 1km to 2 kms, and so on...

To solve this, you can use grouping on the geodist function with frange. Probably something like this,

```
    group=true&group.query={!frange l=1 u=2}geodist()&group.limit=20
```

You can use group.sort also to sort your results within a group.